# SQL Nested Query Calculation

Tags: sql

```
    SELECT *, 
           (select SUM(sl.priceeach*sl.qty) as 'tot' 
                  from salesline sl where sl.soid=so.soid) as 'total',
           so.total,
           so.discount,
           so.tax
    from salesorder so
```

I am trying to figure out this query but I couldn't display the total in another coloumn 
to display the tax included and discount minused data

```
ERROR : #1054 - Unknown column 'so.total' in 'field list'
```

whats wrong with my query ?

Comment: Why have used * with other table columns?

Comment: does the saleslorder table have a column named total?

Comment: It seems there is no column named TOTAL in SALESORDER Table.
Please check it once again

Comment: no salesorder table only has discount and tax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you do not want to use a correlated subquery for this. In fact, you should alost never use them at all as they process row-by-agonizing-row like a cursor.

A CTE or derived table will do the job.

```
SELECT a.total, 
       so.discount, 
       so.tax 
FROM salesorder so 
JOIN 
    (SELECT sl.soid,SUM(sl.priceeach*sl.qty) AS 'total'  
     FROM salesline sl GROUP BY sl.soid) A
    ON A.soid = so.soid
```

Now total is an available column to use in other calculations in your query such as:

```
SELECT a.total, 
       so.discount, 
       so.tax,
       so.tax*a.total as TaxableAmount 
FROM salesorder so 
JOIN 
    (SELECT sl.soid,SUM(sl.priceeach*sl.qty) AS 'total'  
     FROM salesline sl GROUP BY sl.soid) A
    ON A.soid = so.soid
```